# How can I show the last login date and time that user logged in with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this on my login page:

```
   $current_time = date("g:i A");
   $current_date = date("l, F jS, Y");
   mysql_query("UPDATE employees 
   SET last_login = '$current_time', last_login_date = '$current_date' WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

And then on the page when the user is logged in (the protected page) I have this:

```
 [...]

 <?php 
 $last_login_date = $info['last_login_date']; // get last_login_date from mysql table
 $last_login_time = $info['last_login_time']; // get last_login_time from mysql table
 ?>

 [...]

 You last signed in on <?php echo $last_login_date; ?> at <?php echo $last_login_time; ?>.
```

But this doesn't work properly because it shows the time they just logged in. How can I make it show the last time they logged in?

I also even tried adding a `prev_login_time` and `prev_login_date` to the table too, but I don't know how to make it update properly because it would update every time they login making it show the time they just logged in. (so it would be showing the current time to them)

Thanks.

---

## Edit: [for EdoDodo]

Here's the login if statement that is setting the last IP address session variable:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);

     if($count == 1) {

     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
     $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['last_login_time'] = $info['last_login'];
     $_SESSION['last_login_date'] = $info['last_login_date'];
     $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $info['last_login_ip'];
     
         $return = $_SESSION['returnurl'];
         if(!$return) {
         $return = "/employee/";
         }
         date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
         $current_time = date("g:i A");                                                                                                                                                                                       
         $current_date = date("l, F jS, Y");
         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         mysql_query("UPDATE employees 
         SET last_login = '$current_time', last_login_date = '$current_date', last_login_ip = '$ip' WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
         header("Location: $return");
         exit();
     }
```

The last login  date and time is working, which is why I don't know why it isn't working with the IP one. I am accessing it correctly on the protected page:

```
$last_login_date = $_SESSION['last_login_date'];
    if($last_login_date = date("l, F jS, Y")) {
    $last_login_date = "Today";
    }
    $last_login_time = $_SESSION['last_login_time'];
    if($_SESSION['last_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    $last_login_ip = "this IP address (".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].")";
    }
    else {
    $last_login_ip = "IP address ".$_SESSION['last_ip'];
    }                                                                                                                
    echo "Last account login: ".$last_login_date." at " . $last_login_time . " from " . $last_login_ip . ".";
```

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I'm not setting the session variable or retrieving it properly? But it seems like I am. I hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you having PHP generate timestamp strings for this? Just use `now()` inside the query string. Storing dates as strings in mysql costs you the ability to any kind of normal date/time manipulations/calculations on those fields, without expensive per-query on-the-fly conversions.

Comment: true enough, but storing a fully-formatted string still takes up more space in the DB than a native date/datetime field does. And if you later-on decide to change date formats, you'll have to reparsed every single field yourself, rather than just changing a simple format specification.

Comment: Oh, so does `now()` do the same thing as `date("g:i A");` and `date("l, F jS, Y");`?

Comment: no. you'd convert those timestamp fields into actual native date/datetime fields. then now() will insert a native datetime value into those fields (corresponding to the current date/time at the time of insertion). you'd then use `date_format()` in your retrieval query to format the values however you want.

Comment: Oh. Seems like a lot of work though. I'll try it someday. Are you saying the way I'm doing it right now takes up too much database storage or something?

Comment: a timestamp field needs 4bytes, datetime needs 8 bytes. For today's date (Oct 3), your two date formats date up 25 characters, so you're wasting 17 chars worth of space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to fetch the login time from the table in the database into the `$info` array *before* you update the database and overwrite the time with the new one. Then, you'll have the previous login time in the `$info` array (and, if you want to carry it across lots of different page loads, you could put it in a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)).

Comment: Oh yeah! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'll put it into a session variable :) Thanks again.

Comment: For some reason it isn't working all that well with the session variable for the last IP address. I edited my question so you can see my login code that sets the variable for the last IP address. For some reason the last IP address is being the one just logged into. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: I wish someone could help. :/

Comment: I've looked at your code, but really can't see the issue with it, sorry :(. Maybe you could start it as a new question, so more people will take a look at it.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for looking at it. I will post it as a new question.