# php check when last time user visited a page

Tags: php

I have a page `login.php` in which when the user login a `cookie` is set by the `username` just to ensure that if the user comes back again he need not have to log in. But now I need to specify his last visit also. How shall I do that?

**Login.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["checkbox"]) && $_POST["checkbox"]==1) {
    $expire = time() + 365*24*60*60;
}else{
    $expire = 0;
}

setcookie("user", $row['username'], $expire, "/");
```

The above code creates a cookie by the username as soon as the user logs in.

Also I have a file that checks if the user has already logged in and if 'yes' it doesn't let the user enter his credentials again. But now I want when the user logs in a message should appear saying "you last visited the site...".

How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show the last login date and time that user logged in with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637791/how-can-i-show-the-last-login-date-and-time-that-user-logged-in-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in db table, and after each successful login update the login date and time in it.

- **You can find the same question and answers** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637791/how-can-i-show-the-last-login-date-and-time-that-user-logged-in-with-mysql)